# Uncaught TypeError * is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am trying to write and learn using Object.prototype and I am getting the error saying that `this.issue` is not a function when I call it within another method.  What am I doing wrong that is causing it to through this Uncaught TypeError?

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var Example = function() {
       this.number1 = null;
       this.number2 = null;
   };

   Example.prototype.issue = function() {
       //Logic is here...
    };

   Example.prototype.updateNumber = function() {
       //more logic is here...
       this.issue();
   };

   Example.prototype.updateSign = function() {
       //logic here...
       this.issue();
   };

   (function() {
       var solution = new Example();

   })();

});
```

UPDATE: https://jsfiddle.net/czLtc82y/

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a JSFiddle? That'll make it easier to find the issue

Comment: as this is full of "pseudo code", and the real code part of what you've presented is valid, no chance of getting an answer

Comment: @Pikamander2 I will create one right now

Comment: Where did you call `issue()`? If you call `solution.issue()` or `solution.updateNumber()` or `solution.updateSign()` inside your IIFE, it is all right.

Comment: @JasmineOT I am calling this.issue() within .updateNumber & .updateSign.  Also I just attached a JSFiddle

Comment: @Pikamander2 I just updated it with a JSFiddle

Comment: @JaromandaX I just updated it with a JSFiddle

Comment: what does that have to do with the title that states `Uncaught TypeError * is not a function` - that error never happens

Comment: See "Common problem: Using object methods as callbacks / event handlers" in the accepted answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: @JaromandaX if you look in the console that is where the error is appearing one you enter numbers into either of the fields

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling I took a look at that one briefly and it has a ton of great information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At handlers attached to `change` event for `#sign` , `.number`

```
Example.prototype.newNumber = function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.id === 'number1') {
      this.number1 = parseFloat($(event.currentTarget).val()); 
  }
  else { 
     this.number2 = parseFloat($(event.currentTarget).val()); 
  }
  this.issue();
};

Example.prototype.newSign = function(event) {
    this.sign = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    this.issue();
};
```

`this` references `#sign` , `.number` elements , not `new Example` object created by

```
var problem = new Example();
```

Try using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set `this` to  `new Example()` : `problem` within `.change()` handlers

```
(function() {

    var problem = new Example();

    $("#sign").change(problem.newSign.bind(problem));

    $(".number").change(problem.newNumber.bind(problem));

})();
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/czLtc82y/1/

---

Alternatively, using [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy)

```
(function() {
    var problem = new Example();

    $("#sign").change($.proxy(problem.newSign, problem));

    $(".number").change($.proxy(problem.newNumber, problem));

})();
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/czLtc82y/2/

Comment: You might want to expand on why that's necessary.

Comment: @FelixKling See updated post

Comment: Thank you @guest271314 for the answer and for explaining it!